# fsck exit status "System should be rebooted"

Tags: fsck, exit-status

The fsck(8) manpage on Linux includes the following table of exit codes:

```
   The exit code returned by fsck is the sum of the following conditions:

          0      No errors
          1      Filesystem errors corrected
          2      System should be rebooted
          4      Filesystem errors left uncorrected
          8      Operational error
          16     Usage or syntax error
          32     Checking canceled by user request
          128    Shared-library error
```

Exit code 2 has been allocated to 'System should be rebooted', so we can probably assume it has some purpose. Yet in principle `fsck` could return this exit code after checking some kind of external thumb drive that isn't critical to the operation of the system at all. It seems absurd that an error in a non-essential file system like this would necessitate a reboot, especially if the file system has only been touched by `fsck`.

What does a 'System should be rebooted' exit code *actually* mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the filesystem in question was mounted while the check was being performed, `fsck` had to actually modify data on-disk to fix an error, and the filesystem can't be manually remounted without rebooting the system.

The primary case for this is when errors are found (and repaired) on the root filesystem.  Unless you have a really fancy initramfs or recovery environment you're checking the filesystem from, you're running off of the root filesystem while you're checking it (thus it's mounted read-only).

For performance reasons, the kernel doesn't revalidate cached metadata for mounted filesystems (because nothing (other than `fsck` should be changing the data on-disk other than the kernel for a mounted filesystem), so if `fsck` has to fix some of that metadata, it either needs to notify the kernel (which it can't on most UNIX systems), or tell the user to unmount the filesystem and then mount it again to get the kernel to pick up the modified metadata.  The only way to do that with the root filesystem though is to actually restart the system itself.

Comment: Couldn't one just use `pivot_root(2)` to switch to some tmpfs, unmount the original root and re-mount it again? This should address any concerns about cached data structures, but technically isn't rebooting.

Comment: @user3840170 The thing is, a reboot _always_ works, and doesn't need special setup like using `pivot_root`` (or `kexec`) would.  You could indeed do a double `pivot_root` through a specially prepared tmpfs instance (or use `kexec` to just reload the kernel from scratch), but `fsck` can't make the assumption that you have such things set up (or even know how to do so), and absolutely shouldn't do it itself (for multiple reasons), so it's left with the only option being to give the user a simple easily understood result.

Comment: So it really means "filesystem needs a remount", and reboot is the easy and reliable way to do that.

Comment: @starblue Historically, the _only_ way to do that for the root filesystem was a reboot. And even with a modern system designed for it, you need to completely shut down all of userspace to do it because absolutely nothing can be using it, and for most users that’s functionally equivalent to a reboot, albeit possibly much faster.

Answer (score 1):

It really does mean that the system should be rebooted.

`fsck` implementations are typically careful about returning this code only when necessary: for example, `e2fsck` returns it if it corrected errors on the root file system, while it was mounted (it is typically mounted read-only until it’s been checked). You shouldn’t get it on an external drive.

Note that you should check the documentation for the specific checkers being used. For example, `fsck.fat` doesn’t use the same exit codes, and blindly assuming that an exit code of 2 means to reboot could lead to surprises.

Comment: Thing is, the main `/sbin/fsck` binary may use bitwise OR to combine exit codes coming from different filesystem-specific fsck binaries; for this operation to make sense, there really *should* be some common interpretation for these exit codes. `fsck.fat` not using these standard codes is [a bug](https://github.com/dosfstools/dosfstools/issues/89), which presumably will be fixed in some future release.

Comment: Yes, I agree it’s a bug; unfortunately that doesn’t change the fact that you can’t rely on the codes having a common meaning, you need to check first. (And yes, I think all `fsck`s you’d use on a root file system *do* follow the main `fsck` expectations.)

Comment: If the only sensible action in that case is to reboot, why doesn't `fsck` just invoke `reboot(2)` on its own, or send SIGINT to PID 1? The reboot must be for some reason other than 'because I said so'.

Comment: One tool, one job. `fsck`’s job is to check and fix file systems, not to handle rebooting. Arguably the documentation assumes too much; it would be more accurate to say “2 indicates that a mounted file system was altered” (which in practice means the system should be rebooted).